# Netplan Bonding of eth0 and eth1 not working, eth1 going up and down

Tags: networking, server

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Linux desktop that has four ethernet ports. Two are unused (in the future I'll use all four), the first two are being used now. One is connected to a modem so the Linux machine has Internet access. The second used port has an Access Point connected to it. The intention is that the Linux machine acts as a firewall. All traffic should run through it and people connect to the access point. Rather than the Access Point being connected directly to the modem.

The Linux machine has Internet access via the modem successfully. So that portion is working. And when the access point is connected to the modem it works. Therefore the issue lies in the second ethernet port not bonding to ethernet port one.

I have reviewed the following:
https://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-bonding-teaming-in-ubuntu

http://www.techpository.com/ubuntu-bond-two-network-cards-together

https://netplan.io/examples

And I have had no success. How can I fix this? So that if I attach one or more access points to the Linux machine it uses Internet access from the ethernet port of port 1/eth0/enp1s0?

## 01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      enp1s0: {}
      enp2s0: {}
    bonds:
        bond0:
            interfaces:
                - enp1s0
                - enp2s0
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                primary: enp1s0
```

## sudo netplan --debug generate

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: starting new processing pass
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: Configuration is valid
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: enp1s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: Configuration is valid
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: bond0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.573: Configuration is valid
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.574: Generating output files..
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.574: openvswitch: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.574: NetworkManager: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.575: openvswitch: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.575: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.575: openvswitch: definition bond0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:551187): DEBUG: 07:29:35.575: NetworkManager: definition bond0 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:551187): GLib-DEBUG: 07:29:35.575: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
(generate:551187): GLib-DEBUG: 07:29:35.590: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

## dmesg|grep enp1s0

```
[    2.066296] igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[    4.116022] bond0: (slave enp1s0): Enslaving as a backup interface with an up link
[    4.158737] bond0: (slave enp1s0): making interface the new active one
[    7.110596] igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: igb: enp1s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

## dmesg|grep enp2s0

```
[    2.126761] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth1
[    4.088820] bond0: (slave enp2s0): making interface the new active one
[    4.089374] bond0: (slave enp2s0): Enslaving as an active interface with an up link
[    6.870442] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[12780.209083] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Down
[12783.073459] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[12806.913687] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Down
[12809.566095] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[28478.784219] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Down
[28481.500675] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[28505.101057] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Down
[28507.789427] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

Comment: From the usecase you describe, you definitely don't want to bond the interfaces. It sounds like you would just setup each interface normally and route the traffic between the two interfaces.

Comment: @ArturMeinild thank you for the response. I did a search and found this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052789/correct-way-to-route-between-2-interfaces-with-netplan-in-ubuntu-18-04. I think it is what I need instead. I'll give it a try and see what happens.